# why do my 2010 sharepoint sites not show up in Explorer?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am running Windows 7 and Sharepoint 2010.

I followed the directions to Sync Office with my sharepoint 2010 library so that when using Open or Save from Office app i see the Sharepoint libraries in the lefthand navigation pane.

Why can't I see the same libraries through Explorer?

Repro:

1) click Start -> Explorer
2) click on SharePoint Sites

Result:  only the Member Sites (my 2007 sharepoint installation) show. NONE of the 2010 libraries.

any help?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this still works off of the membership list which is compilled during user profile synchronization.  The downside of this feature is that it is based off of adding a user account directly to a contributor group in SharePoint and does not recognize users that are members of a security group added to the Contributor group.  Since best practice is generally to add AD Security Groups to the SharePoint groups, this feature loses value quickly.

Comment: but i am added directly as a user of the sharepoint ownership group. i'm also a member of groups that have lesser permissions that are domain groups. i'm not sure how this answers the question??

Comment: There is a single group identified for membership on a site; by default it is typically the site Members group.  That is the group that counts, and you have to add individuals to that group.  Being added as an individual to the Owner group doesn't trigger membership, nor does gaining membership to the Members group through membership of an AD Security Group.

Comment: To say it a different way, this has nothing to do with actual security or access to the content, its all about how the user's account is associated with a specific group on that site.

Comment: i added myself explicitly to the Members group and now they show up. so much for clean, easy, simple group membership.

Comment: @AprilD. I couldn't agree more, this aspect killed the usefulness of the feature.